# Getting URL from String and sending to another class

Tags: android, arrays, imageurl

I would like to get the ImageURL from the String I have set up.

I know my String "mImageUrl" will give the correct image URL corresponding to the image in which the user is viewing.

How would I be able to get the contents/URL of "mImageUrl" and then send it to another class so it will displayed in an Array of URLs like I have here:

```
Public class Images { 

Public final static String[] myImageUrls = new String [] {

"IMAGEURLSHERE", "IMAGEURLSHERE", "IMAGEURLSHERE", "IMAGEURLSHERE",
"IMAGEURLSHERE", "IMAGEURLSHERE", "IMAGEURLSHERE", "IMAGEURLSHERE",



        };
  }
```

I would like to do this by clicking an item on the action bar like I have set up here:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.SetWallpaper:
        new SetWallpaperAsync(getActivity()).execute(mImageUrl);

        break;


    case R.id.SaveWallpaper:
        new SaveWallpaperAsync(getActivity()).execute(mImageUrl);

        break;

    case R.id.FavouriteWallpaper:
        //Here 



        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because myImageUrls is static you can use it in any other class just by doing `Images.myImageUrls`